# jquery : cannot read property of undefined

Tags: jquery

I want to read a value of a input in a form.

sometimes the the form contains the input

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="123">
</form>
```

sometimes the above input will not be in the form

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

My problem is

I am reading the userid value which throws the error if the input is not there.

```
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
userid = form.userid.value;
```

Because of this error most of the script functionality is not working.

```
if(pack_id !=undefined && pack_id ==''){
  pack_id=0;    
}
```

please help me rectify the error

Comment: can you try like `userid = form.userid ? form.userid.value : "";`

Comment: @vijayP worked thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ext = $('input[name=userid]').length;


if (ext) {
  alert('input is here')

} else {

  alert('not input is here')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

Check the length like `$('input[name=userid]').length` of the input it present or not

Answer (score 1):

You can apply undefined check before getting value

```
if(form.userid!=undefined){
userid = form.userid.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check it by typeof method for userid property is exist or not in form JavaScript dom element object.

```
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
userid="";
if(typeof form.userid !=="undefined" )
{
    userid = form.userid.value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var userIdCheck=$('#userId').val();
if(userIdCheck!=='undefined'){
alert("Ther is a input"+userIdCheck);
}
else{
alert("User Id does not contain the value");
}
```

Try this may helps you